# Populating excel column with values based on matching variable

Tags: excel

I have a table, similar to:

```
Entry_1    5    VarA    Empty_A    Empty_B
Entry_1    3    VarB    Empty_A    Empty_B
Entry_2    6    VarB    Empty_A    Empty_B
Entry_3    2    VarA    Empty_A    Empty_B
Entry_4    4    VarA    Empty_A    Empty_B
Entry_4    9    VarB    Empty_A    Empty_B
```

I want to consolidate the values in the column preceding VarA and VarB variables into a single row, probably to end up with something like this:

```
Entry_1    5    VarA    5    3
Entry_1    3    VarB    5    3
Entry_2    6    VarB    NULL 6
Entry_3    2    VarA    2    NULL
Entry_4    4    VarA    4    9
Entry_4    9    VarB    4    9
```

Once this is done, I have no need for the second column that originally held values or the third column with variable names, so I can remove them, then delete repeat rows to end up with:

```
Entry_1    5    3
Entry_2    NULL 6
Entry_3    2    NULL
Entry_4    4    9
```

So I need something that will either turn my data in to the formatting in the second code block so I can do the rest myself, or something that will jump straight to the final version. How do I do this?

Comment: Looks like a pivot table would do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Some details re @Tim's suggestion:

[image: SO30518626 example]

Comment: Perfect, I haven't used pivot tables before and this here helped me a ton in getting it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I can see how useful they are. I had some trouble adding in a large set of duplicate rows in one PT (my data had about 4-5 duplicate columns besides just Entry_#), but I was able to work around that by creating a few PTs and copying over the columns after. I can tell I'll need to just sit down and work through one or two practice PTs sometime.